# Animation not work properly (performs Only once) in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm showing issues with animation. Animation works fine when i clicked on button to show linear layout when i clicked buttton to close linear layout animation perform as i want but when i click second time to open linear layout animation doesn't work for both to show layout or close layout. I also want to inform you that button click perform properly. layout visibility GONE & VISIBLE works proper but animation didn't work second time.

```
public class AdminViewComplaintActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView btn_search, btn_close_search ;
LinearLayout ll_search;
Animation animationIn, animationOut;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_complaint);

     btn_search = findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
     btn_close_search = findViewById(R.id.btn_close_search);
     ll_search = findViewById(R.id.ll_search);


    animationIn= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.view_in);
    animationOut= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.view_out);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view==btn_search){

      

        if(ll_search.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

 // show linear layout with animation

            ll_search.setAnimation(animationIn);
            ll_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    else if(view==btn_close_search){

// close linear layout with animation

        ll_search.setAnimation(animationOut);
        ll_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      
    }
 }
}
```

xml for animation view_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

xml for animation view_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to view

```
   anim.setFillEnabled(true);
   anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

in programmatically use this :

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.nameYourAnim);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
```

for example anim :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Comment: Use only viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);